# Is this a way to call the model dynamically in MVC 4? (Description inside)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've seen a code, which is in MVC, In that it consists of the following in the view,

```
dynamic r = base.Model.R;

@((dynamic)base.Model.R)
```

and so on. I don't understand this, Is this a way to call model. If someone knows about this please answer me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Razor template gets compiled, `@(...)` expression is replaced by the call to `Write` inside the generated `Execute` method so your example would compile into the following:

```
public void Execute()
{
  // ...
  dynamic r = base.Model.R;
  Write((dynamic)base.Model.R);
}
```

Since `Write` must accept a parameter of type `object`, anything can be passed (so I'm not sure you need a cast to `dynamic` here).

Here's an article that can help you understand how Razor templates are processed: [Leveraging Razor Templates Outside of ASP.NET](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1103081).

As for `dynamic` keyword, this basically tells the compiler that the expression of this type will be *interpreted* at runtime (late binding). Here's some more information: [Using Type dynamic (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

Hope this clarifies things a bit for you.

Answer (score 2):

This `base.Model` is a call to [`WebViewPage.Model Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.model%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), which you can set in [`ViewData` (code samples)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

`dynamic` is a keyword that says the variable is dynamic, the type is computed at runtime.